# MVC4 EF5 My Context won't show up when I'm creating a controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My Context shows up properly when Entity Framework 6.1.3 installed but since scaffolding isn't supported in Entity Framework 6 I had to downgrade it to version 5.0.0. Now when I try to create a new controller my context isn't listed in the drop down list in Data Context Class:

Is this some sort of bug ? [Image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz3e3.png)

What's even more surprising is that it works on a copied version of the same solution.

Comment: rebuild the solution and try again

Comment: scaffloding EF6 not supported??? Really? I can Scaffold in EF6

Comment: @Aizen It won't let me create a new controller ! Error comes out that EF6 doesn't support scaffloding!

Comment: @BhavikPatel It didn't show so I forced it by copying and pasting the Context because it didn't show in the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by Rebuilding Solution, reinstalling Entity Framework 5.0.0 then manually type in my Context into the data context list when adding a controller.